# Embedded H2 Giving java.lang.IllegalStateException: The file is locked: nio:/tmp/h2tmp.680671858.1.temp.db [1.4.200/7]

Tags: java, database, jdbc, h2

I am using H2 Database (version 1.4.200) in my application in embedded mode as a part of a background process. Each time the background process is triggered, a new embedded database is created. the database created is only accessed by single thread and single connection object.
The connection string I use is:
`;FILE_LOCK=NO;LOCK_MODE=0;UNDO_LOG=0;MAX_MEMORY_ROWS=100000;CACHE_SIZE=64000;LOG=0;MV_STORE=FALSE;`

The complete stack trace of the exception is:

```
The file is locked: nio:/tmp/h2tmp.680671858.1.temp.db [1.4.200/7]
at org.h2.mvstore.DataUtils.newIllegalStateException(DataUtils.java:950)
at org.h2.mvstore.FileStore.open(FileStore.java:172)
at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.<init>(MVStore.java:381)
at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore$Builder.open(MVStore.java:3579)
at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTempResult.<init>(MVTempResult.java:184)
at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVPlainTempResult.<init>(MVPlainTempResult.java:67)
at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTempResult.of(MVTempResult.java:83)
at org.h2.result.LocalResultImpl.createExternalResult(LocalResultImpl.java:313)
at org.h2.result.LocalResultImpl.addRowsToDisk(LocalResultImpl.java:353)
at org.h2.result.LocalResultImpl.addRow(LocalResultImpl.java:346)
at org.h2.command.dml.Select.queryFlat(Select.java:739)
at org.h2.command.dml.Select.queryWithoutCache(Select.java:844)
at org.h2.command.dml.Query.queryWithoutCacheLazyCheck(Query.java:201)
at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:489)
at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:451)
at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.query(CommandContainer.java:285)
at org.h2.command.Command.executeQuery(Command.java:195)
... 19 more
```

From what I could understand, H2 will create some temp database files (if a query results in more records than set in MAX_MEMORY_ROWS parameter)

The file that is mentioned as locked is one of these temp files and not the actual database file which I am connecting.

Comment: Can you verify that you did not open multiple instances of your app? and that you are not opening the H2 instance on the same port?

Comment: You're using many dangerous connection options at once, they aren't suitable for normal use cases and may cause various problems.

Comment: @EvgenijRyazanov, I am not sure what do you mean by dangerous connection options. Can you explain a bit.

Comment: `FILE_LOCK=NO`, `LOCK_MODE=0`, `UNDO_LOG=0`, and `LOG=0` should be used with caution and only when you exactly know what are you doing. They may cause data corruption.